# Android Studio exception raised during rendering

Tags: android, android-studio, exception

exception raised during rendering android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nDraw(JJJLandroid/graphics/Rect;ZZ)I
How can i fix it? I dont want to reinstall it. I update AS and this exception was raised.

Comment: Please give us more details. Whole error would be a start

Answer (score 31, accepted):

At the top of the layout editor, change the android version from N preview to an older version, either 23 or 22 should work.

Comment: So there is no way to preview this for version N?

Answer (score 8):

Change the android version from N preview to an older version;

[image: Show picture that shows how to do it]

Comment: How would we actually solve this with previewing N? N is now out, but I can't work around this error.

Comment: Then use last version.don't use N preview.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Preview Android version.. it worked ,in my case.